# What are all these extra icons in the Firefox Address Bar?

Tags: 14.04, firefox

All,

This morning after an update I now have all these icons in the address bar:

[image]

Anyone else seen these before?

Thanks!

-m

Comment: [This person](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/997324) fixed it by disabling an RSS Icon plugin, so plugins would be a good place to start.

Comment: Check whether you can see any unusual extension. Try reinstalling, before that remove all config files

Comment: thanks @Nattgew you can mark that as an answer if appropriate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some questions on [Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/997324) that suggest the RSS Icon plugin can cause this behavior. Starting in [Safe Mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode) can confirm that the problem is caused by a plugin, and then you can proceed to disable plugins to narrow down the culprit.